# matching game for iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Can any one help me to what is basic logic for matching game or memory game?Is there any tutorial or reference is available for this kind of games?please help me to solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

- http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/corona/corona-sdk-create-a-memory-match-game/
- http://codecanyon.net/item/iphone-memory-game/243940
- http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-game-development/13001-tic-tac-toe-tutorial-a-walkthrough.html

Easy google search on what you wanted.